# error: unexpected unqualified-id before '.' token.

Tags: c++

Im trying to make a matrix filled with O chars, but Im new to classes.
When trying to run I get the following error:

error: unexpected unqualified-id before '.' token.

Im doing something wrong with the class, but I cannot find out what. 
Anybody has an idea?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class field
    {

private:

public:
    char** the_field;
    int i, j;
    char**  create_field(void);
    void    print_field();

    };

////////// CREATE THE FIELD //////////

  char** field::create_field(void) //define member function
   {

        for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            the_field[i] = new char [14];

            for(int j = 0; j < 14; j++)
            {
                the_field[i][j] = 'O';
            }
        }
        return the_field;
   }
//////////// PRINT THE FIELD //

    void field::print_field()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 14; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 14; ++j)
            {
                cout << " " << the_field[i][j] << " ";
            }
 //             putchar('\n');
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }

int main()
{
//declare objects with type field
field create_field; //declare create_field as type of field
field print_field;
int i, j;

field.create_field();
field.print_field();

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: don't waste our time, the error message states the line number where the error occurs, please point us to that line.

Comment: Besides the compiler error, you have a more serious run-time error. You don't actually allocate `the_field`, so accessing `the_field[i]` will is undefined behavior and may lead to a crash. Unless you are required to use pointers, you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or possible [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: thank you, it indeed gives a run-time error now. I will look in to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of problems in your code:

- If you create something with new, you have to call also delete on that object
- the_field should be private
- you don't need to define i and j in the class, because they are defined in the for loop already
- you are ignoring what does the create_field() method returns
- the size of the grid is not dynamic (use width and height in simialr situations)
- the_field is pointer to a pointer (2D array in your case), but you are creating just the columns (the rows have to be created also)
- ...

I have fixed it for you, please try it.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;


    class field
    {
    private:
        char** the_field;
        int width;
        int height;

    public:
        // constructor
        field(int w, int h);

        // destructor
        ~field();

        // method
        void print();
    };



    field::field(int w, int h)
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;

        the_field = new char*[width];
        for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
            the_field[i] = new char[height];
            for (int j=0; j<height; j++)
            {
                the_field[i][j] = 'O';
            }
        }
    }


    field::~field()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<width; i++)
            delete[] the_field[i];

        delete[] the_field;
    }


    void field::print()
    {
        for(int i=0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < height; j++)
            {
                cout << " " << the_field[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }



    int main()
    {
        field* myfield = new field(14, 14);
        myfield->print();
        delete myfield;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I learned a lot from your code, it has a really clear structrure. really helpfull. Thanks for the effort! It made the tutorials I read a lot more clear.

Comment: If you are really satisfied, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer, so the others will notice the right answer easily.

Comment: Ok, didnt know about the answer button. I will upvote your answer as soon as I have enough reputation points to be allowed to do so :p thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

How many fields are there? I think you want one field, but you have declared two. I think you want this

```
field my_field;

my_field.create_field();
my_field.print_field();
```

BTW I think you'd agree that this code would read better if your member functions were called `create` and `print`. Generally I don't think it's a good idea to name your member functions after the class they are part of.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the class name. '.' operator is used for objects of class to access their attributes.
If you do :

`field  obj;

obj.create_field();`

then you will not have a problem.
'unqualified id' means you did not give it a valid identifier.
And u did not, because u used the class name instead of an identifier for an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
field.create_field();
```

Should be

```
create_field.create_field();
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
field create_field; //declare create_field as type of field
field print_field;
```

You're creating two variables of type `field`, whose names are the same as member functions of the `field` class. While percfectly legal, it's very confusing, and probably not what you intended.

```
field.create_field();
field.print_field();
```

This is incorrect code, as non-static member functions must be called on an instance of the class, but you're trying to call them directly on the class. You could do that if they were `static`, but then you'd have to use `::` instead of `.`.

This probably wouldn't be what you want, though. I assume you wanted to create one `field` object and then call the member functions on it. The code for that would be:

```
field fieldInstance;
fieldInstance.create_field();
fieldInstance.print_field();
```

---

Side notes about design:

- It's generally a good idea to follow the principle of *encapsulation* with classes. This means data members shouldn't be `public`, they should be hidden under accessors.
- There's little reason to repeat the class name in member function names - they're part of the class in the first place.
- It's usually a bad idea to separate object creation from its initialisation. The code of `create_field()` would be better as the constructor for `field`.
- It's best to avoid manual memory allocation in C++ if possible. Generally, using `std::vector` is far superior to manually allocating dynamic arrays.
- When creating print functionality, it's a good idea to pass in a stream object, so that you can easily redirect the printing.

In summary, I would design your class like this:

```
class field
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char> > the_field;

public:
    field();
    const std::vector<std::vector<char> >& getField() const { return the_field; }
    void print(std::ostream &stream) const;
}

field::field() :
    the_field(14, std::vector<char>(14, 'O'))
{}

void field::print(std::ostream &stream) const
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < the_field.size(); ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < the_field[i].size(); ++j) {
            stream << ' ' << the_field[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        stream << '\n';
    }
}
```

Of course, the `getFied()` functio is actually a bit too powerful, returning a direct reference to the data. It would be better to provide a semantics-based interface tailored to your class' intended use - perhaps `char get(size_t i, size_t j) const`.